# Excel validation of cell as per other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can i validate excel cell from other sheet below is my sheet example want to validate Sheet 1 from Sheet2 as reference.

I have done validation with same rows using FIND , Search function from Right Left but other sheet have no idea seeking for help here

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do here, and I suspect you are not using the term "validation" in the sense that Excel uses it in the "Data Validation" feature.
Aer you just trying to check if the combination of the first two columns appears in the table on sheet 2? Are you always using the first "word" of the second column (all characters before the first space?
Can you show some more varied examples of possible input and expected output in sheet 1?

Comment: What result do you need to output? Could you provide more information?

Comment: Thanks team i am able to resolve it by my own

Comment: You may, for example, combine these 2 columns in some service column with some specific delimiter and use VLOOKUP by these columns for validation.

Comment: =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10,MATCH($A6,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,0)),$B6,1)) used like this to make it work